# Find out why download speed on my laptop is dropped significantly

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

So I have two laptops in same WLAN network, 5 ghz.
I have 100mbit internet connection from provider.
Couple days ago download speed on my laptop only dropped to 1.5 mbit/s.

Below is traffic monitor from my router displaying results of internet speed test.

I have dell latitude 5520 with windows 10 installed.
I tried to reset network with Settings -> Network & Internet -> Status -> Network reset.
It didn't help.
I deleted network adapter from device manager and installed it again.
It didn't help.

Please help to diagnose the issue and fix it. Any suggestions appreciated.

[image: speed test]

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

I plugged in network cable, turned off wi-fi and triggered speed test.
It shown 100 mbit/s.

Then I unplugged network cable, turned on wi-fi and triggered speed test.
It shown 100 mbit/s.

That's pure mistery and I don't know why it solved that way. I guess some bugs in Windows 10 21H1 19043.1320